# $P$, $Q$ are projections on a Hilbert space such that $|P-Q|<1$ then $\dim(\operatorname{Range}(P))=\dim(\operatorname{Range}(Q))$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

$P,Q$ are projections on a Hilbert space such that $|P-Q|<1$ then  $\dim(\operatorname{Range}(P))=\dim(\operatorname{Range}(Q))$.

Is there a intuition for this to happen, also I am not being able to solve it.

Comment: What is the meaning of $R$ ?

Comment: And $|\_|$ is the induced operator norm on the Hilbert space?

Comment: yes, you are right

Comment: R denotes range

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you are considering finite rank projections. Let their ranges be $M$ and $N$. Define $T: M \to N$ by $Tx=Qx$. Then $T$ is linear. If $Tx=0$ with $\|x\|=1$ then $\|Px-Qx\|=\|x-0\| =\|x\|=1$ and $\|Px-Qx\| \leq \|P-Q\|<1$  which is a contradiction . Hence $T$ is a one-to-one linear map from $M$ into $N$. Since $M$ and $N$ finite dimensional this implies $dim(Range(P)) \leq dim(Range(Q))$. Now just reverse the roles of $P$ and $Q$ to get the reverse inequality.

Comment: Why is $T$ linear?

Comment: $T$ is linear because $Q$ is linear. The standard definition of a projection on a Hilbert space is  a bounded linear map $P$ such that $P^{2}=P=P^{*}$.

Comment: But why is $Q$ linear? We only know $Q$ is a projection, i.e. $Q^2v = Qv \forall v$.

Comment: If $Q$ is not linear its range need not be  subspace. What do you mean by its dimension? @RGS

Comment: I am just saying that those conclusions, that appear to "fall from the sky", should be included in the answer. Otherwise the OP is likely to be confused and unable to fully understand the answer. Much like when you write *$||Px - Qx|| = ||x - 0|| = ||x|| < 1$ contradicting the hypothesis*. Which hypothesis? $||x|| = 1$ or $|P - Q| < 1$? Your answer is a bit convoluted, overall